# Exercise 8.1.H from Vakil's FOAG: criterion for ideals in affine open sets defining closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

I'm trying to solve the following exercise, namely Exercise 8.1.H, from Vakil's FOAG:

[image]

As hints, there are three approaches provided, of which I'm following roughly the first. The way I want to do this is to first define schemes $Y_i \cong \text{Spec }A_i/I(A_i)$, for each affine open $\text{Spec }A_i\subset X$. Next I wish to glue them in the obvious way.

For any distinguished open $\text{Spec }A_f\subset \text{Spec A}$, suppose we have, for some indices $A_i = A$ and $A_j = A_f$. Since we're given that $I(A_i)_f \cong I((A_i)_f)$, we have isomorphisms $(A_i/I(A_i))_f\cong (A_i)_f/I(A_i)_f\cong (A_i)_f/ I((A_i)_f)$. We use this to define isomorphisms $\phi_{ij}: \text{Spec } A_j/I(A_j)\to \text{Spec } (A_i/I(A_i))_f$, where $\text{Spec } (A_i/I(A_i))_f$ is an open subscheme of $Y_i$.

Next I want to define $\phi_{ij}:Y_i\to Y_j$ for arbitrary $Y_i$ and $Y_j$. To that end, in $X$, I cover the intersection of $\text{Spec }A_i$ and $\text{Spec }A_j$ with affine opens which are simultaneously distinguished opens for both $\text{Spec }A_i$ and $\text{Spec }A_j$. Now, if $\text{Spec }A_k$ is one of these distinguished opens, then I already have isomorphisms from an open subscheme of $Y_i$ to $Y_k$, and from $Y_k$ to an open subscheme of $Y_j$, from the previous paragraph. Finally, I want to show that it is possible to glue of all of these composites, to obtain $\phi_{ij}$. The $\phi_{ij}$ I just defined can be made free of the choice of the cover by distinguished open sets, by simply taking *all* such distinguished opens in the intersection, as the cover for the same.

Lastly, I need to check that the $\phi_{ij}$ agree on triple intersections (i.e. this is the cocycle condition). I'm not entirely sure how to do this, but I think it suffices to cover the triple intersection by affine opens which are distinguished in all three intersecting affine opens?

To conclude, my requests are as follows:

1. Am I heading in the right direction?
2. As is evident from the above, I haven't yet worked out the full details. Thus, I would appreciate feedback on the approach I've taken, and possible ways of making the solution cleaner.
3. I would be really grateful if someone can either post a complete solution to this or provide a reference where this has been worked out in detail, with machinery restricted to what Vakil has developed so far in the text.

Thank you.